# How do I update my scale to take my axis into account

Tags: graph, d3.js, zooming, scale, axis

I'm trying to update my axis with custom labels because I want my users to be able to use different datasets. The current array of label names i load in have 17 elements in it.

When loading the page the graph only shows 11 elements as it can be seen here: http://servers.binf.ku.dk/hemaexplorerbeta/

How do I update my xScale to be able to all of the elements at once?

Here's the code for my scale:

```
    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-25, genWidth])
        .range([0, width-margin.right]);
```

And for my update function:

```
    function updateAxisX(arr) {

        var formatAxis = function(d) {
           return arr[d % arr.length];      
        }

        xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom")
            .tickFormat(formatAxis);


        SVG.select(".x.axis")
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-65)" 
                });
    }
```

I also have a zoom function where you can drag the graph around as well. As I mentioned the X Axis has 17 element in total, although on my graph they are repeated over and over. Is there any way I can prevent the zoom from letting the user drag the graph out of my "maximum" frame? In other words I'd like to be able to drag ONLY IF there has been zoomed in on the graph and ONLY until you reach the "edges" of the graph and no more.

Here's the code for my zoom function:

```
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(xScale)
        .y(yScale)
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on("zoom", zoomTargets);

    function zoomTargets() {
        SVG.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-65)" 
                });
        SVG.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
        SVG.selectAll("circle").attr("cx",function(d){return xScale(d)}).attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(d)});
    }
```

Also don't mind the huge red circles, they are just randomly made for testing something.
I should also mention that my graph is supposed be a scatter plot by the time I get everything done.

One quick question as well. Since I'm not using numbers, but custom labels where I've inserted strings. How do I insert the my circles accordingly to each spot on the x axis?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4987520)?

Comment: Yes, I have. Although I'm confused to how I use what I think is something in between the constrained zoom and the zoom I currently have. When I used the same constrained zoom from the example my axis is zoomed in on too. I'd like the axis zoom to work as it is now and the rest of the area to use the constrained zoom. How do I prevent the axis from get zoomed in on is my question, I guess.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. So you want to disable the zoom?

Comment: Yes I think so, I want to have a constrained zoom while keeping both axes on the left and bottom of the graph and while keeping their sizes of the font and lines as they are. When I use the constrained zoom, the axis will literally grow larger with the elements of my graph. If I for example zoom in the middle of the graph with the constrained zoom, the axis won't be in the view-able section of the avg any longer.

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3892928). You don't actually need to zoom the entire canvas.

Comment: I used this example to make my current zoom. And if you look at the website I linked to and try and zoom, you can see that it will merge the x axis labels together or split them when you zoom in and out, which I don't want. I made a quick drawing of what it is I want. It's a lot easier than explaining: http://puu.sh/7T532.png

Comment: I should also mention that, the axis behave almost the same way as the second example you linked to. The only difference is that it adds more numbers when you zoom in. If you for example take the values 0 and 100 and zoom in around there you will eventually have 0, 50 and 100 on the axis. Since I use custom labels for my graph I need it to not do that.

Comment: Ok, so you basically want the zoom example but with specified axis labels? You can use `.tickValues()` to specify explicitly where ticks should appear.

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I'd also like to have a panning/zooming limit. I can see that tickValues only uses integers. For this specific dataset jeg have 17 ticks for the x axis. This means I'm supposed to define 17 ticks with in tickValues, right? But if the user chooses to use another dataset that only has 14 ticks on the x-axis for the graph. How can I make the tickValues automatically adjust?

Comment: Ok, so a combination of constrained zoom and custom ticks. If you use `.tickValues()`, you need to compute the ticks yourself. If you want to adjust for new data, you have to recompute.

Comment: Ah yes, okay. I will make a function that can handle solve that. I have one thought about my scale. When changing the amount of my ticks I'm going to update the domain of my xAxis Scale as well, so that all the content will be visible IF for example a dataset with more than 17 ticks is added. I seem to have trouble re-adjusting the scale. When changing the domain, I update my yAxis, xAxis and circles. It changes it just fine, although my zoom function stops working. Why is that? Am I supposed to apply the scale change to the zoom as well?

Comment: Yes, if you change the scales and they are linked to the zoom you need to update that as well.

Comment: Okay, can I assign an `.attr("class", niceZoomFunction)` to my zoom to be able to select it later and let it know that the change has been made? Because I don't know how else to select it and call it

Comment: I have no idea what you mean -- are you not talking about the zoom behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just had to use zoom.x to change the scale of my zoom. It was THAT easy..